# IIS and Chrome - corrupted Javascript from IIS (looks ok in Fiddler)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iis, corruption

I have a very simple website that I've just migrated to IIS (7.5), and while it works in IE the javascript is corrupted in Chrome, looking like Chinese characters according to the dev tools.

A Fiddler trace shows it to be identical for both browsers so I'm v confused!

Start of JS in Fiddler:

```
// Comment
$(function(){
```

Start of JS in Chrome dev tools:

```
⼯䌠浯敭瑮␊昨湵瑣潩⡮笩ਊ瘉牡映汩浥湡条牥㴠␠✨昮汩浥湡条牥⤧ਬउ牢慥捤畲扭⁳‽⠤⸧牢慥捤畲扭
```

Maybe some sort of Unicode thing? Changing the file didn't help (added the comment at the top), and the response headers look OK:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/x-javascript
Last-Modified: Thu, 14 May 2015 06:37:44 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "c7bdb97b108ed01:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Date: Thu, 14 May 2015 06:48:28 GMT
Content-Length: 8273
```

It also doesn't work on mobile Safari but I can't see the content easily to tell if it's the same problem.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Can you test in FireFox / safari desktop?

Comment: I think its compressed and not corrupted.

Comment: Unfortunately Safari desktop no longer exists for Windows, which is a pain for testing. It isn't compressed according to Fiddler, and I also realised the simple test to access the JS directly myself - it's fine in all browsers.